# как менять местами слова в вертикальной строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как можно сделать, чтобы при выводе строка выводилась RU | ENG, как бы слова менялись наоборот, при этом сама html строка не изменилась, изменения были только в css.

```css
 .table {
position: relative;
top:-10px;
color: #070707;
    }
  
    .eng {
     color:#828282;
    }
    
    .language{
     margin:2em;
     font-weight:700;
     font-size:36px;
     font-family:sans-serif;
    transform-origin:left top;
    transform-box:fill-box;
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
    
  }
```

```html
 <div class="language" id="language">
                    <span class="eng"> ENG</span> | RU
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если всё таки есть возможность поменять HTML, то можно сделать так:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('.language').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --nonactive: #828282;
  --active: #070707;
}

.language {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.language .-sep {
  white-space: pre;
  color: var(--active);
}

.language:not(.active) .eng {color: var(--nonactive);}
.language:not(.active) .ru {color: var(--active);}

.language.active .eng {color: var(--active); order: 2;}
.language.active .ru {color: var(--nonactive); order: -1;}
```

```html
<div class="language active" id="language">
  <span class="eng">ENG</span>
  <span class="-sep"> | </span>
  <span class="ru">RU</span>
</div>
```

JS используется для демо, по нажатию на страницу он будет добавлять\удалять класс с блока `.language`.

Comment: Мне кажется проще было вешать класс на элемент с текстом "ru"/"eng", а сепаратор делать через бордер.

Comment: Суть как раз в том, что вешается на родитель и в зависимости от наличия класса меняется поток элементов через `order`. Можно и менять классы у элементов, но задача требует смену на CSS. Сепаратор можно и `border`, и псевдо-элементом, как угодно, но у автора это символ)

Comment: А если в будущем будет три языка, как тогда?

Comment: Ну вешать не `active`, а `active-%lang%` и расписать чуть больше стилей. Я согласен с вами, что проще это решить на JS, но опять же, хоть и присутствует метка JS, речь в вопроса шла про CSS)

Comment: Так мы вешаем класс на нужный язык, который через ордер и сделает его первым.

Comment: Только вот у меня дикий вопрос, как быть с разделителем, ибо при `order: -1`, он все равно может быть `:last-child`